# Capacitor discharge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance

Consider Figure (a) that shows a capacitor with equal and opposite charges placed on the two plates. If the capacitor is considered *ideal* then the electric field developed is shown as depicted.

[image]

For an *ideal* capacitor, when two conductors are placed as shown in Figure (b) then, presumably, there will be no charge redistribution since there is no electric field present in the respective regions to move charge around. It then follows that if the circuit is completed by adding a resistor that no current will flow (see Figure (c)) and the capacitor will not discharge, even though there is a potential difference. Of course, for any real capacitor, the discharge appears to be driven by the presence of fringe fields, see Figure (d).

[image]

Two related questions:

If an *ideal* capacitor doesn't discharge and real capacitors do discharge because of the presence of *fringe fields*, why is the formula for the discharge current given by

$$ I (t ) = \frac{V_0}{R} e^{-t/RC}$$

applicable ($V_0$ is the initial potential difference across the capacitor)?

Comment: Any capacitor can discharge due to dielectric or vacuum breakdown between plates, given extreme enough electric field in between plates. That's how lightning works.

Comment: Charge will redistribute to the wires. Capacitors do discharge.

Comment: Like charges repel.  This means that a wire connecting the two capacitor plates of a "perfect" capacitor will experience a current flow.

Comment: Charges move under the influence of electric fields, in the absence of an electric field there is nothing to push or pull electrons on the upper and lower parts of the plates, respectively. I have suggested real capacitors work because of the presence of fringe electric fields.

Comment: If you squeeze the bottom of the toothpaste tube, toothpaste comes out the top. Your personal theory is incorrect.

Comment: This is an excellent conceptual question, certainly not deserving downvotes. My reading of it is that (as Gauss's law shows) there is no electric field outside the capacitor in the vicinity of the connecting wire stubs [diagram (b)], so how can a current go through the resistor [diagram (c)]? Completion of the circuit by a conducting path must alter the field pattern, but I am not competent to develop this idea into a convincing answer.

Comment: Please don't just say "all images taken from the internet". Proper attribution requires giving the actual sources and link(s).

Comment: If two conductors are connected, electrons will move between them (in both directions). If a conductor joins the two plates, electrons will be able to move between the plates (in both directions). If the plates are identical (apart from charge) more electrons will move away from the negative plate, just because there are more there than on the positive plate. This will discharge the capacitor.

Comment: @jim I did not vote to close the question, but I'll note that replacing "perfect" by "ideal" is not an improvement since you are still referring to an electric field that violates the laws of electromagnetism.  Also, your revised question refers to "two related questions", but your edit removed one of them. Finally, removing "all images taken from the internet" is actually worse, since it leaves the impression that you might have created the images yourself. Aside from giving links being the correct thing to do, seeing your sources might help people understand your thinking.

Answer (score 3):

There are electric fields outside any finite "perfect" charged capacitor  consistent with classical electromagnetism, so the answer to your question (1) is "No", and question (2) is moot.

Figures (a-c) do not show a "perfect" capacitor, they show an imaginary capacitor that has an electric field that does not obey Maxwell's equations. Just apply [Faraday's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday%27s_law_of_induction#Maxwell%E2%80%93Faraday_equation) to the circuit including the wire and resistor:
$$\oint \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{l} = - \int \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{A}$$
Since there is initially no magnetic field, there must be an initial electric field that will drive the current flow discharging the capacitor.

The fringe fields at the edges and outside of a finite capacitor are not imperfections, they are required by Faraday's Law (as discussed in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aM9I46RberU)).  This imaginary capacitor's electric field is often a useful simplified approximation when the plate separation is small compared to its width, but it is important to only use this approximation where it is valid, i.e. inside the capacitor away from the edges. Trying to apply the approximation to the electric fields near the edges or outside the capacitor, as you have done, just leads to erroneous confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> When two conductors are placed as shown in Figure (b) then, presumably, there will be no charge redistribution since there is no electric field present to move charge around.

In a real circuit, the wire used to connect to the resistor are not ideal 0-ohm resistors, and so there will be an electric field present in them when they are connected between two capacitor plates with a potential difference between them. This will cause a current to flow and the capacitor will discharge.

If we want to consider the wires as ideal and that there can be no field within the wires, we must also remember that when the wire is ideal a non-zero field is not required for current to flow. If that seems counter-intuitive you need to remember that the wire is not actually ideal, and the ideal case is just a limiting model for a wire with a very small but non-zero resistance.